# How to increase the array by 1 with each input

Tags: c#, arrays

My goal is, at every new input to the question which i marked, the array gets a new input.
For example:

```
double[] Test = new double[10];
"give input" | 
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) |
Test[0] = input |
```

> Again to "give input". just that circle and with every input the "Test [HERE]" gets there a new input. (Like if u would do that manually)

sry for my bad english. english insn't my native language.

````
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mittelwert();
        }
        public static void Mittelwert()
        {
            double[] Test = new double[10];
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie ihren " + i + " Wert ein");
                int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Test[+1] = input;

            }
            var Average = Enumerable.Average(Test);
            Console.WriteLine("Der Durchschnitt ist " + Average);

        }
    ```
````

Comment: Change `Test[+1]` to `Test[i]`

Comment: @TheBatman i've already tested it. i get the error: "index was outside the bounce of the array"

Comment: Why not use `List<T>`? They increase in size automatically as you add new items.

Comment: @s0lid The first element of the array is `Test[0]`, not `Test[1]`, and the last element of the array is `Test[10]`, not `Test[11]`. You need to change your loop. Arrays are zero-indexed. The number in the brackets should be considered an offset from the origin (0), and not the position of the element.

Comment: @maksymiuk great idea. Thank you. I didn't ever really use a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `i` as the index of the array, but note that C# arrays are zero-based (i.e., the first index is `0`, the second is `1`, etc):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie ihren " + (i +1) + " Wert ein");
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Test[i] = input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want to iterate a number of times over a *collection* and once the iterator passes the length of the *collection*, you want to essentially append new items to the end.

For this `Array`s are not the best option, you want to instead use `List<T>` which scales up as you add new items.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mittelwert();
    }
    public static void Mittelwert()
    {
        List<double> Test = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie ihren " + i + " Wert ein");
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Test.Count < i)
                Test[i] = input;
            else Test.Add(input);

        }
        var Average = Enumerable.Average(Test);
        Console.WriteLine("Der Durchschnitt ist " + Average);

    }
```

Comment: loop still needs to start from 0

Comment: I just copied his code verbatim because I don't want to assume the use cases. There are plenty of cases where you may want to start an iteration from numbers other than 0.

Comment: name some use cases where you're enumerating an array and skip only the first element

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you just create the list with a capacity of `11` instead?

Comment: @RufusL The 11 I am assuming is just a representation to have a larger amount of iterations than items in the collection. It can be any number, and we don't necessarily know at execution that it will be smaller or larger than the collection capacity. For purposes of this answer, it is a constant, but only for visual purposes. To show clearly that the iterator will go out of the bounds of the collection.

Comment: @TheBatman you can have an iterator that iterates over an array but you don't care about the first item. In my experience at least this is a very common practice, if I know beforehand that I don't care about x number of indexes from beginning or end, its a good idea to optimize them out of the loop completely

Comment: In this case, however, it appears he's using the `i` value more for the display to the user (i.e. "Enter your 1 value", "Enter your 2 value", "Enter your 3 value"). My guess is starting from `0` is more correct, then adding `1` to `i` for the display message.

Comment: @RufusL in your use case, that would be correct. However I don't want to assume the use case of the OP since it can go in many ways and is irrelevant to the issue at hand.